# Meaning of output of "svn stat -v"

Tags: svn

Where's a SVN reference manual that can explain the meaning of the output of output of "svn stat -v"?

Searching google just gives development noise.   The main online manual (http://svnbook.red-bean.com) is a user guide not a reference manual and doesn't seem to have 'stat -v' in it.

Thanks
Ben

Comment: `svn help stat` explains every column in the output. The SVN book has it as well, in *Chapter 9. Subversion Complete Reference*, in the section *svn-Subversion Command-Line Client, svn Subcommands, svn status (stat, st)*

Answer (score 2):

The information *is* in the [red book in Chapter 9](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.ref.svn.c.status.html):

> The first column indicates that an item was added, deleted, or otherwise changed
>
> The second column tells the status of a file's or directory's properties
>
> The third column is populated only if the working copy directory is locked
>
> The fourth column is populated only if the item is scheduled for addition-with-history
>
> The fifth column is populated only if the item is switched relative to its parent
>
> The sixth column is populated with lock information
>
> The seventh column is populated only if the item is the victim of a tree conflict
>
> The eighth column is always blank
>
> The out-of-date information appears in the ninth column (only if you pass the `--show-updates (-u)` option)
>
> The remaining fields are variable width and delimited by spaces. The working revision is the next field if the `--show-updates (-u)` or `--verbose (-v)` option is passed.  If the `--verbose (-v)` option is passed, the last committed revision and last committed author are displayed next.